# apt-get commands pausing at 'Waiting for headers'

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a VM running Ubuntu Server 9.10 running a basic web server setup. Whenever I run an apt function it will pause for around 1 minute at 'Waiting for headers...'. It will eventually clear through and continue as normal but it is a bit of an annoyance.

Everything else on the server seems to run fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using another mirror? Any additional repositories?

Comment: For me it was because I was connected to my work VPN - couldn't connect to `deb.nodesource.com`, for instance. Disconnected from VPN - no problem. Connect again to VPN - problem. Won't be the source of the problem for everyone but if you are using a VPN and having this problem, try disconnecting. (can't post answer 'cause not enough rep)

Answer (score 13):

Some repos have issues with http/1.1 pipelining.

Try adding the following to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/piplining-off.conf:

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth "0";
```

Comment: Brilliant!! added it and apt-get update works even better!! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out your multiverse and universe repos in your */etc/apt/sources.list*

Then do a: **apt-get clean all**

then finally an: **apt-get update**

See if that clears it up some.

Answer (score 2):

**tldr;** Software Source -> Download From -> Other -> Choose Best Server

I had this problem with an ubuntu install. To debug the problem I edited 
`/etc/apt/apt.conf` and added `Acquire::http::Timeout "3";`
 which gives a really short timeout and makes it much more obvious what the problem is.

apt-get update then showed a lot of 404's from `http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com` which was the repository my ubuntu install had chosen.

Under software sources I then went to Download From -> Other -> Choose Best Server. It chose a server in Bulgaria - which actually happened to be the same server, which I suppose bg.archive.ubuntu.com is aliased or redirected to. But in any case, after selecting that server directly rather than the .archive.ubuntu.com alias, apt-get update worked perfectly. This suggests there can sometimes be some kind of problem with DNS or aliasing with the *.archive.ubuntu.com server names, which can simply be resolved by using another server, or even the same server directly by it's non-aliased name.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your time & date is set correctly,

I had the same problem and fixed it with a simple `ntpdate`

Also, find out what it's doing by running `sudo strace apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I was connected to my work VPN - I couldn't connect to `deb.nodesource.com`, for instance. Disconnected from VPN - no problem. Connect again to VPN - problem. This won't be the source of the problem for everyone but if you are using a VPN and having this problem, try disconnecting and then trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ISP first if possible, 80% of the time, this is caused by the proxy settings on the ISP side, or server proxy configs.
After troubleshooting for hours including a few modifications in /etc/apt/apt.conf,I just switched my ISP and within 20 seconds I go my updates and nginx installed.

Comment: i belive your question is off-topic, moreover this question is ehm 11 years old, i belive the VM does not exists anymore